# Diode behavior past forward voltage

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I have recently being learning more about how diodes work. From what I understood when you bias the diode with forward voltage you are lowering the built in barrier (or from another point of view giving extra energy to electrons to overcome the barrier) so the number of electrons (and holes) that can pass the barrier grows exponentially. What bothers me is that everywhere I look in the internet they use the exponential equation for the diode even past the built in voltage. Shouldn't be linear past that voltage? Because you are giving enough energy to all the electrons to pass the barrier so it should behave like a conductor. At least that is what I think, is there something I´m not taking into account? Even if that is not true I still don't see where does the exponential increase in current comes after the built in voltage.

Comment: Why should the equations governing carrier behavior change all of a sudden?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In the diode equation, why the exponential $\exp$ and the ideality factor $n$ are there? What do they represent & what is their significance?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53199/in-the-diode-equation-why-the-exponential-exp-and-the-ideality-factor-n-ar)

Comment: In that link it says: "When you increase the (forward) bias on the diode, the hill begins to become flatter. Because the electrons are distributed exponentially in height above the our imaginary landscape, it means that a linear change in the voltage causes an exponential change in current" but still dont understand what happens after forward voltage because all electrons should have enough energy to pass the barrier.